# C# - cannot update mysql database column value

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database, winforms

I am having trouble updating the column `onlinestatus` in my MySQL database. I made a picture showing what I want to achieve and how the database looks like (excuse me for my Paint skills hehe).

[image]

Here is the code I am using:

```
string connString = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=rookstat;Uid=XXXXXX;password=XXXXX;";
        using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var command = new MySqlCommand())
            {
                command.Connection = connection;

                command.CommandText = @"
                UPDATE rookstayers SET level = 0 WHERE name = @name;
                UPDATE rookstayers SET onlinestatus = 0;
                DELETE FROM rookstayers WHERE name = @name;
                INSERT INTO rookstayers (name, sex, vocation, level, achievements, world, lastlogin, accountstatus, onlinestatus) VALUES (@name, @sex, @vocation, @level, @achievements, @world, @lastLogin, @accountstatus, @onlinestatus);
                ";
                command.Prepare();

                foreach (var rooker in Players)
                {
                    command.Parameters.Clear();
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", rooker.Name);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sex", rooker.Sex);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vocation", rooker.Vocation);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@level", rooker.Level);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@achievements", rooker.Achievements);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@world", rooker.World);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastLogin", rooker.LastLogin);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountstatus", rooker.AccountStatus);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@onlinestatus", rooker.OnlineStatus);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                Players.Clear();
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
```

So I basically want it to clear the level and onlinestatus, delete existing row, insert the players.

Note: **the name is always unique** in my application.

Note 2: if I delete the `UPDATE rookstayers SET onlinestatus = 0;` line, it will add all players and give them the online status 1 like it should. But this application is a cronjob for a game and refreshes every 30 minutes. This causes a problem if the player logout in the game. Their online value stays at 1. That's why I want to set ALL players in database to onlinestatus 0 (offline) before inserting. Then insert them. Because all the players I insert are taken from the online list, meaning they are online.

Comment: seeing as that statement works on the entire table running it for every player in players seems pointless and or mistaken. Should it be just name, or should you run it separately?

Comment: Well I want every player in the database to get onlinestatus = 0, which I get. After that I want to insert my list of players that I have into the database, which should update their onlinestatus to 1. It works for my level column, I don't know why it does not work for my onlinestatus column. If I for example manually set one of the players level to 1000, and run my application now, it will first set the level to 0, then insert the current level again (50 for example). About the DELETE, I am not sure how else to do this. I just dont want it to make duplicate players (same name) in the database

Comment: Since the names are unique, 1 row is always 1 player.

Comment: What I would really like is an IF-ELSE-THEN , but I have no idea how to add that, I keep messing it up all the time. For example, if name = @name, then only update the values, ELSE add a new player........ basically check if a player name exists in the database, if so: update their LEVEL and ONLINESTATUS only! if the player does NOT exist, insert the name/sex/vocation/level etc... on a new row in database

Comment: I'm not a MySQL guy, but in order to get rid of your delete, this would work in T-SQL.  `INSERT INTO rookstayers (name, sex, vocation, level, achievements, world, lastlogin, accountstatus, onlinestatus) SELECT @name, @sex, @vocation, @level, @achievements, @world, @lastLogin, @accountstatus, @onlinestatus WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM rookstayers where name = @name);`  Another option would be to use MySQL's `MERGE INTO` statement.

Comment: What can you tell us about the table?  Can you give us data types?  Any constraints?  Triggers?  Also, is the insert failing, or inserting something other than you expected value into the OnlineStatus column?

Answer (score 0):

Oh.  I think I see what's happening.  You're C# code is iterating each rooker in your Players "collection".  Every time you do that you're running 4 queries.  One of those 4 queries is updating every record in the table so that onlinestatus is zero, including all the records that you've inserted so far.  So only the last record inserted will have an online status of 1.  All the others will have been updated to 0.  (repeatedly.  this is very inefficient.)